# How change the IP address of the computer on Windows 10?

Tags: windows, networking

My PC has Windows 10 since I bought it. The computer network works with a WIFI router with a static IP address. I recently discovered that the current internal address of the network has changed from 192.168.8.5 to 192.168.8.115 I wanted to change through Control Panel-Network and Internet-Network Sharing Center. But I discovered that there is no such possibility here anymore. How to change the IP address of the computer on Windows 10?

Comment: Why do you think you need to change it? If it works as it is, leave it alone. your DHCP server will handle this just fine for most consumer uses. if you need to map a static address to your computer, you should do this from the DHCP server, not from the local computer.

Comment: wanted to change through Control Panel-Network   .... Still there, Windows 7, 8, 10 and 11.   Why not use DHCP Reservation on your router to give the computer a fixed address. Works much better.

Comment: @Harry Welcome to Super User.  As you can see, your question was migrated here from ServerFault.  Since you've never logged in here, you can't currently comment on or accept answers on your question.  If you'd like to, just use the same login here on Super User that you did on Stack Overflow and Server Fault.  Note that this question is being discussed on [meta.superuser.com](https://meta.superuser.com/q/14738/1210833).

Answer (score 2):

### To enable DHCP or disable or change other TCP/IP settings

- Select Start , then select Settings  > Network & Internet .

Do one of the following:

- For a Wi-Fi network, select Wi-Fi  > Manage known networks. Choose the network you want to change the settings for, then select Properties.
- For an Ethernet network, select Ethernet, then select the Ethernet network you’re connected to.
- Under IP assignment, select Edit.

Under Edit IP settings, select Automatic (DHCP) or Manual.

- To specify IPv4 settings manually

Under Edit IP settings, choose Manual, then turn on IPv4.

- To specify an IP address, in the IP address, Subnet prefix length, and Gateway boxes, type the IP address settings.
- To specify a DNS server address, in the Preferred DNS and Alternate DNS boxes, type the addresses of the primary and secondary DNS servers.
- To specify IPv6 settings manually

Under Edit IP settings, choose Manual, then turn on IPv6.

- To specify an IP address, in the IP address, Subnet prefix length, and Gateway boxes, type the IP address settings.
- To specify a DNS server address, in the Preferred DNS and Alternate DNS boxes, type the addresses of the primary and secondary DNS servers.

When you select Automatic (DHCP), the IP address settings and DNS server address setting are set automatically by your router or other access point (recommended).

When you select Manual, you can manually set your IP address settings and DNS server address.

When you’re done, select Save.

Credits goes to

- Source: [Microsoft site](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/change-tcp-ip-settings-bd0a07af-15f5-cd6a-363f-ca2b6f391ace#WindowsVersion=Windows_10)
- Google Search Pattern: [Site:microsoft.com change ip](https://www.google.de/search?q=site%3Amicrosoft.com+change+ip)

Comment: Whilst perfectly correct, i do have the sneaky feeling that the OP is likely to dial in an address collision without knowing how to fix it ;)

Comment: Could be, but at the corrent point it was not on topic and asked :p

Comment: Framing challenge would be important here tbh... If someone asks how to best cut their nails with a santoku knife, it's best to *also* explain there are safer options like nail clippers :)